# JSFiddle failing to provide buttons for DataTable to export as Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatable

I am trying to get the DataTable JQuery plugin to export a simple table as Excel, rather than CSV.

My own code at least shows the buttons, but on this JSFiddle I cannot even get that:

https://jsfiddle.net/4tuupc5f/4/

Why does this, with all the plugins resources referenced, not provide an Excel button which exports as Excel?..

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        'excel'
    ]
} );
```

Comment: You have more `columns` in the options than in your HTML, see this working: https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/4tuupc5f/1/ . Try to debug your code in your browsers console before asking questions, your fiddle generated an error.

Comment: I see that is a problem, but it doesn't solve the problem. Why is the DataTable not providing the Excel export button?

Comment: Are you including the right libraries?

Comment: I'm not sure; I was hoping someone could tell me. Having said that, if I need to reference a swf, how would I do that on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacause you miss the two most important parts :

- Inclusion of the plugin source itself https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
- You never tell dataTables that you want to use the button plugin. Include the buttons plugin either by using the `B` `dom` option or use

  ```
  new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( ...)
  ```

Besides that, you might want to include the CSS file

https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css

and of course the PDFmake-library files :

https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/4tuupc5f/6/**

Comment: I can't seem to find the packages that you've referenced in your JS Fiddle. I've been looking in bower and npm.

Comment: buttons.dataTables.min.css

Comment: OK. See **https://datatables.net/download/bower** you need both `datatables.net-buttons` (the js file) and `datatables.net-buttons-dt` which hold the CSS, including `buttons.dataTables.min.css`, have just checked with a `"datatables.net-buttons-dt": "*"` and a `bower update`, now you should have the CSS as well :).

Comment: @MattW, Another tip: You should not go beyond jszip 2.6.0, i.e `"jszip": "2.6.0"` (perhaps 2.6.1) to my experience there is compatibility problems if you use 3.0.0 or higher.